# HUDSON: How to stop hudson job from command line?

Tags: hudson, hudson-api

I need to forcefully stop a Hudson build running in remote server. Is there a command/API to do that?

for ex: to trigger a new build we can do :- HUDSON_URL/job/JOBNAME/build

looking for similar API to stop the build.

Answer (score 10):

You should be able to make a http request to

`http://HUDSON_URL/job/JOBNAME/BUILDNUMBER/stop`

and you can do a xpath request to get the build number

`http://HUDSON_URL/job/JOBNAME/api/xml?xpath=//lastBuild/number/text()`

There may be a way to put in latestBuild or lastBuild instead of BUILDNUMBER, but if not, you can just use 2 http gets.

Answer (score 3):

From the above answer (upvoted), @girishs' comment, and some work of my own, in a Windows environment (Linux could probably use `wget` instead of `curl`, haven't tested):

```
curl --request POST -u <USER>:<PASS> "%JENKINS_URL%/job/%JOB_NAME%/lastBuild/stop"
```

...which stops the most recent build without any future config editing. All you need is your user/pass combo.

Comment: If you don't want to put a clear-text password into a shell script, you can replace <PASS> with the user's API token. Still not great security, but slightly better. (Source: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients)