# Stop a Jenkins build with Python

Tags: python, build, jenkins

I'm looking for a method to stop the execution of a Jenkins build. This job is composed by several python scripts, and I want to the first is able to stop it, according an argument passed to the build. I know stop one script, but how stop the entiere build ?
Can I do that with python ? Or with a plugin ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Jenkins API for Python here:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jenkinsapi

You can also just do a `wget` to `http://<hudson_url>/job/<JOBNAME>/lastBuild/stop`.
More details on the above in this answer [HUDSON: How to stop hudson job from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777538/hudson-how-to-stop-hudson-job-from-command-line)

Comment: It seems to me that this API is deprecated.
But "http://<hudson_url>/job/<JOBNAME>/lastBuild/stop" is exactly what I need! Thank you!