# Stop Jenkins build for specific job via REST

Tags: jenkins

How can I stop Jenkins build for specific job?
I am looking for REST API

I did not find such in documentation

**EDIT**

The tricky part is that I need to fetch the running build ID somehow so I can send

```
http://HUDSON_URL/job/JOBNAME/BUILDNUMBER/stop
```

Comment: Try jenkins cli API like described there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777538/hudson-how-to-stop-hudson-job-from-command-line

Comment: In question mentioned before was solution for your case http://stackoverflow.com/a/25979739/1003030 just use lastBuild instead of  BUILDNUMBER